# BlackBerry J2ME Efficient Coding GuideLines? Could Somebody elaborate this?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I found the folliwing code sample in [BlackBerry Java Development, Best Practices](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5827/BP_Writing_efficient_code_446999_11.jsp). Could somebody explain what the below same code means? What is the this in the code sample poining to?

**[Avoiding StringBuffer.append (StringBuffer)](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5827/Avoiding_using_StringBufferappend_StringBuffer_447057_11.jsp)**

To append a String buffer to another, a BlackBerry® Java Application should use `net.rim.device.api.util.StringUtilities.append( StringBuffer dst, StringBuffer src[, int offset, int length ] ).`

**Code sample**

```
public synchronized StringBuffer append(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof StringBuffer) {
        StringBuffer sb = (StringBuffer)obj;
        net.rim.device.api.util.StringUtilities.append( this, sb, 0, sb )
        return this;
    }
    return append(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the `StringBuffer` class is not implemented efficiently. Java Strings are supposed to be immutable, that's what StringBuffer is used for. However, the StringBuffer class you're using is not efficient when using `StringBuffer.append()` so you need to use `net.rim.device.api.util.StringUtilities`. That's what the code is doing, encapsulating the use of that class in a new append() method.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer does not offer an overload for the append() method that takes another StringBuffer.  This means developers are likely to use `StringBuffer.append(String str)` and call .toString() on the second StringBuffer.  This requires the second buffer to be turned into a string, which is immutable, and then the characters from the string are appended to the first StringBuffer.   Thus every character in the second buffer is touched twice, and there is the unnecessary allocation of the String just to transfer the characters to the first StringBuffer.

The efficient way of doing this would copy each character from the second buffer onto the end of the first.  However, StringBuffer does not provide any easy way of doing this.  Thus the recommendation is to use StringUtilities.append(StringBuffer, StringBuffer) which is able to directly read the characters from the second buffer without copying them into an intermediate collection.

This saves the runtime of the extra copying, the runtime needed to allocate a temporary String, and the memory needed to allocate a temporary string.